# Android phone crashes instead of displaying a "Force Close"

Tags: android

I currently work on an Android application with two developpement phones :

- 1 SGS GT I-9000 with  Android 2.3 at first, then Cyanogen 10.1.3 with Android 4.2
- 1 SGS III GT I-9300 with Android 4.0.4

My problem is that when my application triggers an unhandled exception while testing my code, the behavior is radically different on the two handsets : The old Galaxy S displays a force close popup (either on Android 2.3 or 4.2), but the Galaxy S III completly crashes and I have to reboot it each time.

Is there a parameter that i have missed ?

Edit : I also tried to run the app on AVD with a deliberate NullPointerException. It is correctly trapped.

Comment: The phones are different and they have different adaptation code. Sometimes a bug manifests itself in low-level code causing e.g. a kernel panic and reboot. It's easier to start fixing your bugs from the Java side, looking at the logcat exception stack trace from the force close. To get help with that, include relevant logcat and code in the question.

Comment: Think you missed the point of my question. I do not ask for help on a specific Exception or Code problem. I can read LogCat by myself. I only wonder why one handset will correctly trap the unhandled exception and display a ForceClose popup (as intended), while the other will **always** crash a need a reboot.

Comment: *Usually* you'd get the "force close" with exception stacktrace on all devices. No special settings needed. But there are differences between devices and *sometimes* a bug can manifest itself as a system-level crash. Often it's when you're working close to the metal e.g. with bitmaps, GPU acceleration and so on.

Comment: My application does not use low-level code. But to be completly sure, I created a brand new Android project with a blank activity and added those two lines in the onCreate method : Bundle bundle = null; bundle.clear(); My SGS I traps correctly the NullPointerException, but the SGS III craches :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get rid of this problem : I downloaded a new ROM for SGS III and flashed the phone with ODIN 3.09. Exceptions don't crash the handset anymore and the force close popup is correctly displayed.

(For those who wonder why i didn't simply update the current ROM, the response is : I tried, but it changed nothing)